# Github doesn't detect new folder

Tags: git, github, localhost

I am working with the Github windows client connected to my remote bitbuckket git. I recently started building a mobile version of my application in /mobile

I have been working in localhost/WEBSITENAME but am now in loaclhost/WEBSITENAME/mobile with the git repository folder set to the WEBSITENAME folder.

After creating the new folder Github is not detecting the new folder preventing me from pushing my new files.

Comment: dont you need to add them before the push? `git add --all`

Comment: I have tried to do the `git add --all` and it returns `fatal: not a git repository mobile/extensions/gqt.bars/iscroll/../../../.git/moduels/iscroll`

Comment: Please provide more information. Did you cloned the repository from a remote? Is it a new repository? What is the root of your repository?

Comment: I cloned the repository from bittbucket dragging it into Github for windows. Have been working on it fine for a few days now and have had no problem making commits. If I modify a file in the root witch is C:\xampp\htdocs\mab
I have no issues.
I created
C:\xampp\htdocs\mab\mobile
Sense I cloned it locally.
I want to commit everything in the \mobile folder but it won't come up or let me push it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your directory structure looks like this:

```
/------WebsiteName/
        |
        |-----------/Mobile/
```

Then make sure you are in WebsiteName directory, then run `git status`

If you are still getting the same error then run the following in order:

```
git init
git status //here you should see the mobile folder and its files
git add --all
git commit -am "committing"
git push --all
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this next time I have a new folder.

Comment: I was having a similar issue to Kara's with Eclipse and your solution helped me. Thanks.

Comment: I am having same problem. But `git status` not recognizing folder and it's files. Also there is not any .gitignore file too. @meda

Comment: `git add .` then `git status` again

Comment: Terrible suggestion -- afterwards I was able to add/commit but when I tried to push got error: "fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository"

Comment: You need to run git init. My answer is correct you did something wrong

Answer (score 79):

Git will ignore empty folders. Make sure at least one file is present in the new folder in the Git repository, or else you are not able to add it.

Comment: Their is multiple files in the folder

Answer (score 10):

Make sure that there is no .gitignore file anywhere in the folder that is blocking the specific folder you are trying to add or the file or its extension

Comment: Also check a few levels above your folder. For example in my case I had a folder in repo > folder1 > folder2 > folder3. And in folder3 I had a gitignore but couldn't find anything that would lead to this issue, and then I realized there was a .gitignore at the folder1 level that had exclusions leading to my missing folder.

Answer (score 7):

In that case you should check whether you have put `/mobile` in your .gitignore file. Or the solution provided by @meda would work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem

and didn't find the root of the problem but i found a way to solve my problem.

1. First of all, make copy of local MOBILE folder and delete it.
2. open your git in internet browser.
3. go to your WEBSITENAME directory.
4. find `create new directory` button in the user interface and create MOBILE
   directory.

   This action will be pushed as a new commit in the current git branch.
5. run `git pull` in local, and see the created diretory
6. copy the old MOBILE directory into new one.
7. run `git status` and you see every thing is OK

I hope helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and a figure out that's come from the content in file `.gitignore` . The content was like this : `"# created automatically /n *"`. and the fatal is `"*"` : it means you ignore all coding file in this resposity, so the `$git status` cant detective the coding file. just delete the `"*"` in `.gitignore` . it may the point.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a wrong repository  So make some small modification, push the repo and check if the last update is of few moments back.